# Is ζ={∅, ζ} a set according to "Axiom of Regularity"?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

For the following paragraph, I do not understand the {{∅, ζ}} part.

> What about something like ζ = {∅, ζ}? Now that ζ contains the empty
> set, it’s not in obvious violation of the axiom of regularity. But it
> is in fact in violation. Here’s the argument: Start with ζ. Pair it
> with itself to form {ζ}. Now ask, does {ζ} contain any sets that it
> shares no elements with? It’s easier to see if we expand this using
> the definition of ζ: {ζ} = {{∅, ζ}}. The problem is that {ζ} contains
> just one set, ζ, and ζ and {ζ} share an element: namely, ζ itself! So
> in fact, even adding the empty set won’t help us. The axiom of
> regularity rules out any sets that contain themselves.

[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://risingentropy.com/introduction-to-mathematical-logic-part-4-zermelo-fraenkel-set-theory/)

So, i think it like this;

1. We could select the element "ζ" from the set {∅, ζ}.
   And we pair the element "ζ" with set ζ={∅, ζ}.
   "ζ" is also a set which is {∅, ζ} and when we get intersection with the set ζ={∅, ζ};
   Then we get {∅, ζ}.
   So, intersection is **not** empty set(not ∅). This is against Axiom of Regularity.
2. We could select the "∅" element(so I select it because it is a set too).
   And we pair the "∅" element with set ζ={∅, ζ}.
   And when we get intersection of "∅" with the set ζ={∅, ζ};
   Then we get "∅".
   So, intersection is empty set.
   Thus, axiom of regularity.
3. According to "1", we have an element of ζ that is against axiom of regularity.
4. But according to "2", we find an element in ζ, namely ∅ which intersection with ζ is ∅. Thus, **there is at least one** disjoint element as Axiom of Regularity requires. So, this set ζ is valid according to Axiom of Regularity.

**Question:** So, am I doing anything wrong here?

**Side Question:** I am selecting an element from a set if it is actually a set i.e. from ζ={∅, ζ} set, I select "∅", "ζ" as these are already sets. If there is some element "a" in ζ which is not a set, then I will not select it. Am I doing right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the argument. The set $\zeta$ itself does not directly violate regularity, because $\zeta$ does contain an element whose intersection with $\zeta$ is empty: $\varnothing\in\zeta$, and $\varnothing\cap\zeta=\varnothing$. The problem is that if $\zeta$ is a set, the pairing axiom tells us that $\{\zeta,\zeta\}=\{\zeta\}$ is also a set, and **it** violates regularity: its only element is $\zeta$, and

$$\zeta\cap\{\zeta\}=\{\varnothing,\zeta\}\cap\{\zeta\}=\{\zeta\}\ne\varnothing\,.$$

Comment: Why do we pair it with itself? Axiom of regularity does not talk about it; Take sets and its elements.

Comment: Do not we get another separate set when we pair it?

Comment: So, i think pairing a set with itself gives an identical set, is this true?

Comment: @lockedscope: The pairing axiom says that if $x$ and $y$ are sets, there is a set $\{x,y\}$ whose members are precisely $x$ and $y$; there is no requirement that $x$ and $y$ be distinct sets, so if $x=y$, the pairing axiom gives us the existence of the set $\{x\}$. This is **not** the same as $x$: it is the set whose only member is the set $x$. We use the pairing axiom to get the set $\{\zeta\}$; before we did so, we had only the set $\zeta$, which is not the same set.

Comment: So, we could say x and {x} are same things because of pairing axiom. If A={c} and B={{c}} then they are equivalent?

Comment: @lockedscope: Absolutely not! I just said that they are **not** the same thing. The pairing axiom merely allows us to say that if $x$ is a set, then so is the **completely different** set $\{x\}$.

Comment: So then when we have a set x then it **allows** the existence of a **completely different** set {x} so then this violates regularity. I think i got it now.

Comment: @lockedscope: The existence of $\{x\}$ does not in general violate regularity. It is specifically the set $\{\zeta\}$, where $\zeta=\{\varnothing,\zeta\}$, that violates regularity.

Comment: Thanks, i see it, the point is **pairing allows existence of something else**.

Comment: So, i think, we could continue pairing, x, {x}, {x, {x}} ... and all possibilities.

Comment: @lockedscope: One can form these sets, but doing so has nothing to do with the original question.